# Unity. Instantiate object in Local Space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates

This should be simple!

I'm trying to instantiate a particle effect on my character, and i need it to be +1 on the Z axis of the characters local space.  i.e.  so its always +1 in front of the character.

This is my current code:

```
public void PlayEffect()
        {
            Instantiate(slashEffect, wielder.transform.position + new Vector3 (0, 1, 1), wielder.transform.rotation) ;
        }
```

Currently this is causing it to spawn always z+1 in world space,  meaning sometimes its infront of my character and sometimes its behind me, depending on which way i'm facing.

What is the correct way to do this? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Transform.TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)

> Transforms position from local space to world space.

like e.g.

```
public void PlayEffect()
{
    Instantiate(slashEffect, wielder.transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3 (0, 1, 1)), wielder.transform.rotation) ;
}
```

This takes the `0, 1, 1` as a vector in the local space of your `wielder` meaning, if you would create a child object and set this to be its local position, this is where your object will be spawned in world space.

Note that this takes also the scaling of the `wielder` into account!

If you do not want to take the scaling into account rather use the [`Quaternion` operator `*`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) like

```
public void PlayEffect()
{
    Instantiate(slashEffect, wielder.transform.position + wielder.transform.rotation * new Vector3(0, 1, 1), wielder.transform.rotation) ;
}
```

What this does is using the world space offset vector `0, 1, 1` but then rotates that vector without chaning its magnitude according to the `wielder` rotation in the world space.

Answer (score -1):

Our you can try:

```
public void PlayEffect()
        {
            Instantiate(slashEffect, wielder.transform.localPosition + new Vector3 (0, 1, 1), wielder.transform.rotation) ;
        }
```

as transform.localPosition takes local position of that gameobject.

Comment: That doesn't do what is asked for. This uses the local position (in the parent object space) like if it was a world position and then adds the world delta vector (0,1,1) to that already wrong position ... ;) OP wants to spawn the object in the world space relative to the wielder object taking the orientation of it into account

Comment: @derHugo Hmm... I was thinking it in the wrong way then... Thanks man <3